# How to print the result of `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a new to tensorflow, so I try every single command appeared in the official document.

How can I properly print the result `dataset`?  Here is my example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
```

```
sess = tf.Session()
X = tf.constant([[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]], [[3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7]]])
Y = tf.constant([[[11]], [[12]]])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))

dataset
print type(dataset)
# print help(dataset)
# print dataset.output_classes
# print dataset.output_shapes
```

Comment: What about `print(dataset)`?

Comment: `print(dataset)` gives `<BatchDataset shapes: ((?, 2, 3), (?, 1, 1)), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>`

Comment: What would you expect instead?

Comment: My expected output is like `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],[11]` and `[[3,4,5],[5,6,7]],[12]`, i.e. feature paired with its label.

Comment: You might use `list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())`. For testing you can also do `for x in dataset.take(10).as_numpy_iterator(): print(x)`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default TensorFlow builds up a graph rather than executing operations immediately. If you'd like literal values, try [`tf.enable_eager_execution()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager):

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.enable_eager_execution()
>>> X = tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],[[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]])
>>> Y = tf.constant([[[11]],[[12]]])
>>> dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
>>> for x, y in dataset:
...   print(x, y)
... 
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 3]
 [3 4 5]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor([[11]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[3 4 5]
 [5 6 7]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor([[12]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=int32)
```

Note that in TensorFlow 2.x `tf.enable_eager_execution()` is the default behavior and the symbol doesn't exist; you can just take that line out.

When graph building in TensorFlow 1.x, you need to create a `Session` and run the graph to get literal values:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> X = tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]],[[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]])
>>> Y = tf.constant([[[11]],[[12]]])
>>> dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
>>> tensor = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
>>> with tf.Session() as session:
...   print(session.run(tensor))
...
(array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]], dtype=int32), array([[11]], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: Thanks! Please be aware that make_one_shot_iterator() is now deprecated; we don't need the iterator anymore. The workaround is simply to write:

for x,y in dataset:
    print(x,y)

Comment: Good point, I've removed make_one_shot_iterator from the eager execution example.

Answer (score 0):

In latest documentation

```
for element in dataset:  
  print(element)
```