# Print the value in the variable which is set using tensorflow high API

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently, I tried to touch tf.data.Dataset API.

I wish to print the value such as:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.range(10))

print(dataset)
```

It not work.

Error :

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'

My expected results should be:

```
dataset: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes. I get the error like TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856880/how-to-print-the-result-of-tf-data-dataset-from-tensor-slices

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dataset is a list

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.range(10))
print(', '.join(data))
```

Also look at pprint for debugging..

```
from pprint import pprint
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.range(10))
pprint(dataset)
```